# how to set 2 rows to become header in a dataframe with originally has a header?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am facing problem on how to set another 2 rows be my header.

In a dataframe I have one header, and now I want take my first row and second row become header. Below is my dataframe code:

```
pvm=pd.DataFrame(pvm)
```

How can I add `header=[0,1]` into above code?
Or need start from the table style?

```
tableyy = final.style.set_table_attributes('border="" clas= "dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"').set_precision(10).render()
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data? `pvm` is `DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with assign to columns names:

```
df.columns = [df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1]]
```

and if need remove this rows:

```
df = df.iloc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns.names = (None, None)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

df.columns = [df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1]]
df = df.iloc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns.names = (None, None)
print (df)
   1  4  7
   2  5  8
0  3  6  9
```

Comment: but in my case the original header ABC I need to remain, so that I have 3 header, if I apply this ABC was disappear , any idea to remain this ABC?

Comment: no problem, only add `df.columns = [df.columns, df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully understand what you want to achieve, but I will try to guess:

> `pvm.columns = ['0', '1', *df.columns[2:]]`

is it what you intend to get?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})
print (df)
print('==========')
df.columns = ['0', '1', *df.columns[2:]]
print (df)
```

gives:

```
"""
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
=========
   0  1  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
"""
```